# Return to console object attributes

Tags: python, oop, methods, attributes, self

- I have 2 classes - Card and Hand
- Card is with attributes : suit, rank
- Hand is created by appending empty list by cards. So it`s attributes
  are cards.

I ***need to be written in console*** something like:

```
Ace D , Queen H
```

I found in Google that I need to right  `__str__(self)` method carefully.
I do not know how in method `__str__(self)` write stuff that my output would be like I mentioned above. For example :

```
return self.hand
```

does the following :

```
[<__main__.Card object>, <__main__.Card object>]
```

I think that Hand object is a list of such kind :

> [[card 1],[card 2],..]

which is

> [[suit 1,rank 1],[..,..],..]

But I do not know how to take that information from list of list. 
**Such write does not help:** *hand[i][0] for suit and hand[i][1] for rank of i-th card*
Still do not get . Here is code:

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, rank):
        if (suit in SUITS) and (rank in RANKS):
            self.suit = suit
            self.rank = rank
        else:
            print "Invalid card: ", suit, rank

    def __str__(self):
        return self.suit + self.rank

class Hand:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = []
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.hand)
    def add_card(self, card):
        self.hand.append(card)
```

Creating OBJECT CARDS

```
c1 = Card("S", "A")
c2 = Card("C", "2")
```

Creating OBJECT HAND

```
test_hand = Hand()
```

Adding cards to hand

```
test_hand.add_card(c1)
test_hand.add_card(c2)
print test_hand
```

result is:

```
[<__main__.Card object>, <__main__.Card object>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Card() class you could add a `__str__()` method similar to

```
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.rank, self.suit) # assuming Python2.7+
```

Now when you print a Card instance it will return a user friendly string like `Ace D`

To print something nice for your hand instance, you could use the `.join()` string method and a generator inside `__str__()`.

```
def __str__(self):
    return ', '.join(str(c) for c in self.hand)
```

Now when you print your hand instance it will give a user friendly output like

```
Ace D , Queen H
```

A good resource to learn more about `__str__()` and `__repr__()` is [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python).

Edit: If you add the recommended `__str__()` methods to your updated code the output is what you want:

```
A S, 2 C
```

Comment: Thank you! I have one more questions. I am not sure, if I am formulating my question right, please correct me:  Is this the only way to gather information about my Class instance(objects c1,c2) from being in the Hand class? And, for example, if I want to do something with Card`s variables in methods of Hand class.